# SSL - Access non secure API from secure page

Tags: php, security, ssl

I'm developing a plugin for a third party's checkout page, which checks an ID against another third party's API. The flow goes something like this:

Checkout (Secure) - My Server (Insecure) - Private API (Insecure)

Through JS, my plugin makes a get recuest to my server, which in turns makes a get request to the private server. My server processes that info and then responds accordingly.

The problem is that, the Checkout page doesn't get my server's response because of mixed content.

Now I understand why this happens. So my question is: if I secure my server, will it solve this issue? or will it continue complaining (because of that last insecure link)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the private API call server-side or client-side?

Comment: Then the browser will have no idea about whether it was HTTP or HTTPS (in fact, the browser won't even know there's a behind-the-scenes API call happening at all).

Comment: That was the essence of my question. Thank you both for answering!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you secure your server, with HTTPS traffic instead of HTTP, then browsers will not show you mixed content errors anymore.

[Here](https://www.globalsign.com/en/blog/how-to-fix-mixed-content-warnings-on-your-ssl-site/) is a article by the Globalsign blog about mixed-content.

> A mixed-content warning means that there are both secured and unsecured elements being served up on a page that should be completely encrypted. Any page using an HTTPS address must have all of the content within coming from a secured source. Any page that links to an HTTP resource is considered insecure and is subsequently flagged by your browser as a security risk.